# Can an astronaut ever reach a Black Hole theoretically?

Tags: black-hole, astrophysics, fundamental-astronomy, supermassive-black-hole

Ok, bear with me, while I try to explain the question I have.

I read that time slows as we approach a black hole.

So, suppose,theoretically, as astronaut is approaching a Black Hole. And he gets near enough now that time starts slowing down.

If you remember this equation: v=d/t  So, at the moment, t is going infinity, so it means 
V is going zero.
So the astronaut can never the reach the Black Hole because time is slowing down and its taking longer and longer for him to approach the Black Hole.

But then again, we know, a Black Hole sucks everything and that light cannot even escape it.

So, what's happening to the equation above then? [ this time it means v is going infinity and so, t is almost zero], so the astronaut will be sucked almost immediately.

Which one is the correct theoretical answer?

Comment: Time slows only for him, so from his point of view he's sucked even more quickly

Comment: If time is moving slowly, then it's taking longer no? So for the astronaut's view point, its taking ages, but from the Black Hole's 'viewpoint' its very fast and instantaneous.

Comment: Your last statement considers point of view of the astronaut.

Comment: can you explain how you know  that the astronaut's view point will be: he will sucked to the BH instantly? That is my original question actually. That I am not sure, which one is suppose to happen to him  1) wait infinite time to reach the BH or 2) get sucked in immediately. Because both seems to be happening at the same time.

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/does-matter-accumulate-just-outside-the-event-horizon-of-a-black-hole
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21319/how-can-anything-ever-fall-into-a-black-hole-as-seen-from-an-outside-observer

Comment: Beware the answer in the link @zhermes posted which the questioner ticked as the answer is seriously suspect and does not reflect conventional thinking on the matter

Comment: Also related: [Would time go by infinitely fast when crossing the event horizon of a black hole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2524)